# Insert new column in Pandas based on element found via BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a dataframe that consists of tables. The number of tables can be between 3 to 6 and changes daily.  I've cut out the details, but here's what the HTML looks like. There is a table title called "list-title" and a list of table rows called "list2" which I have successfully extracted via pandas.

```
<span id="list-title">
ABC(11111)
<br>
</span

<table class="list2">
<tbody>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<span id="list-title">
DEF(22222)
<br>
</span>

<table class="list2">
<tbody>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<span id="list-title">
XYZ(33333)
<br>
</span>

<table class="list2">
<tbody>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
  <tr class = "bg3" </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I've used the following code to extract the tables and have concatenated as one big table.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


filename = r'\\server\user\someone\Desktop\test.html'
path = open(filename, 'r')
destination = r"\\server\user\someone\Desktop\test_result.xlsx"

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), 'html.parser')
df = pd.io.html.read_html(filename, encoding='Shift JIS', attrs={'class':'list2'})

df = pd.concat(df)

#remove all rows containing Total
df = df[df.isin({'Total'}).sum(1) == 0]

#Even Rows
df_tmp1 = df.iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True)
df_tmp1.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)

# Odd Rows
df_tmp2 = df.iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)
df_tmp2.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

What I need to do is to create a new column and export information from "list-title" per table.

```
broker = soup.find('div', id='mainContents').find_all(id='list-title')[1]
broker = broker.get_text()
df = pd.concat([df_tmp1, df_tmp2], axis=1)
df.insert(5, 'New_Column', broker)
```

What the above code does is that it adds the second title as "broker" for all the tables, not per table. I've tried using for loops such as

```
for i in range(3):
    df = df[i] = pd.io.html.read_html(filename, encoding='Shift JIS', attrs={'class': 'list2'})
    broker = soup.find('div', id='mainContents').find_all(id='list-title')[i]
    broker = broker.get_text()
    df.insert(5, 'New_Column, broker)
```

but this causes an error. I think I need to insert the column before I concatenate the tables but don't know how to.

Comment: is that a typo? `df.insert(5, 'New_Column, broker)`? You are missing the single quote for `'New_Column` -> `df.insert(5, 'New_Column', broker)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to loop the imported tables and brokers and add the broker column to each dataframe before you concatenate:

```
tables = pd.io.html.read_html(filename, encoding='Shift JIS', attrs={'class':'list2'})
brokers = soup.find('div', id='mainContents').find_all(id='list-title')

for (t, b in zip(tables, brokers)):
    t['broker'] = b.get_text()

df = pd.concat(df)
```

Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Hi Eliot, thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for!  I've never used zip before but good to know I can reduce so much coding with this command. Thank you once again.